# Deep reflection fails in xxSkin classes

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java-9

Since update 9-u175, java permits illegal access by default thus allowing all the old reflection tricks. Works fine, except when it comes to classes in control.skin (maybe others as well, didn't check) - to reproduce, run the example below, click the button and see how access succeeds until the line that tries to access a private field in ButtonSkin. The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: 
Unable to make field private final com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin.behavior accessible: 
module javafx.controls does not "opens javafx.scene.control.skin" to unnamed module @537fb2
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
```

My context: jdk9-u175, eclipse-oxygen-R with patch for java9, access rules in the project are set to allow javafx/**

The question is: who's the culprit? FX, Eclipse, the ea or ..?

The example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler;

public class AccessFieldFX extends Application {

    private Parent getContent() {
        Button button = new Button("something to click on");
        // okay
        Object def = invokeGetFieldValue(Button.class, button, "defaultButton");

        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            ButtonSkin skin = (ButtonSkin) button.getSkin();
            // okay
            LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler cl =
                    (LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler) invokeGetFieldValue(SkinBase.class, skin, "lambdaChangeListenerHandler");
            // okay
            Object clField = invokeGetFieldValue(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.class, cl, "EMPTY_CONSUMER");
            // failure
            Object beh = invokeGetFieldValue(ButtonSkin.class, skin, "behavior");
        });
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(button);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent(), 600, 400));
//        primaryStage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static Object invokeGetFieldValue(Class declaringClass, Object target, String name) {
        try {
            Field field = declaringClass.getDeclaredField(name);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field.get(target);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(AccessFieldFX.class.getName());
}
```

Comment: I reproduced the error on 9+178. Indeed, very strange error!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent accidental dependencies on new APIs, illegal access is only granted to packages that existed before Java 9 - I hence assume `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior` is new.

In his [mail with the revised proposal for `--illegal-access`](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-June/012841.html) Mark Reinhold writes (emphasis mine):

> `--illegal-access=permit`
>
> This mode opens each package in each module in the run-time image to
>      code in all unnamed modules, i.e., code on the class path, **if that
>      package existed in JDK 8**.  This enables both static access, i.e., by
>      compiled bytecode, and deep reflective access, via the platform's
>      various reflection APIs.
>
> The first reflective-access operation to any such package causes a
>      warning to be issued, but no warnings are issued after that point.
>      This single warning describes how to enable further warnings.
>
> **This mode will be the default for JDK 9.**  It will be removed in a
>      future release.

Comment: that's it: javafx.scene.control.skin is new in java9 (moved from internal api com.sun... into public) So we need the --add-opens ... of the skin package now and in future .. sigh Thanks!